# Ontario HST rebate: I live in Quebec. Are the rebate cheques for Ontario residents only?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate, quebec

HST cheques are for Ontario residents only? Thought it was Canada. I live in Quebec. So we don't receive a cheque? But will have to pay the HST on all items purchased?

Answer (score 4):

**Correct, the Ontario HST rebate is for Ontario residents only.**  The Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit (OSTTB) is related to the introduction of the Harmonized Sales Tax (HST) in Ontario, and is a program introduced at the *provincial level*, although **Canada Revenue Agency** is assisting the province administer the program by determining who is eligible and by issuing the cheques/deposits.

Coincidentally, British Columbia is also introducing HST on the same date as Ontario – July 1st, 2010 – but B.C. didn't choose to offer a similar payoff to residents to make swallowing the new tax easier.

**Quebec**, on the other hand, doesn't call its sales tax a Harmonized Sales Tax (HST) - instead, it continues to label the federal sales tax separately as the Goods & Service Tax (GST) and the provincial sales tax as Quebec Sales Tax (QST).

What is interesting about Quebec QST is that it applies on top of GST as well; i.e. tax on the tax.  In terms of changes: Quebec will be *raising* its QST from 7.5% to 8.5% in 2011, and 9.5% in 2012 (source: [Wikipedia - Sales taxes in Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sales_taxes_in_Canada)).  But again, this is unrelated to the HST introduction in Ontario.

Finally – yes, if you were to purchase something in Ontario, e.g. online / mail order, before July 1, 2010 you would have only had to pay GST (*not* GST+PST), but after the HST is introduced you will pay the full HST which includes the provincial portion.